# Consultar y obtener dos datos de dos colecciones diferentes - Mongodb - Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Quiero hacer una consulta a mi bd donde me traiga dos datos.

Tengo una coleccion "Clientes" y otra "Registros".
Mi idea es que en la misma consulta donde traigo los datos de un cliente por su ID, tambien me traiga todos los datos de la coleccion "Registros" que contenga esa ID.

Intente hacer esta consulta; 
Pero me falla en cierto modo, ya que me devuelve el cliente pero no el registro

```
  app.get('/:id', (req,res)=>{

  var id = req.params.id

 var cliente =  Cliente.findById(id,(err,cliente)=>{

    if(err) return res.status(500).json({
      ok:false,
      mensaje: 'Error al cargar cliente'});

    if(cliente) return res.status(200).json({
      ok:true,
      cliente: cliente
    })
  });


  var registro =  Registro.find({assigned: id}, (err, registro)=>{
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            mensaje: 'Error cargando registro',
            errors: err
        });
    }

    if(registro){
        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            registro: registro

        });
    }

});

return res.status(200).json({
  ok: true,
  cliente: cliente,
  registro: registro

});

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De las cosas que te fallan es que al obtener el cliente y validar que existe en ese momento envias el response que solo contiene el cliente, te propongo lo siguiente, ¿porque no tratas de obtener primero al `client` una vez que valides que existe dentro del mismo callback ahora mandes a llamar a `registro`? te anexo como sería

```
app.get('/:id', (req,res) => {

  var id = req.params.id

  var cliente =  Cliente.findById(id,(err,cliente)=>{

  if(err) return res.status(500).json({
  ok:false,
  mensaje: 'Error al cargar cliente'});

  if(cliente) {
    //despues que vefiriques que ya cuentas con el cliente manda a traer el registro
    var registro =  Registro.find({assigned: id}, (err, registro)=>{
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            mensaje: 'Error cargando registro',
            errors: err
        });
      }

      if(registro) {
        //validas el registro y envias el response
        return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        cliente: cliente,
        registro: registro
        });
      }

    });
  }

  });

})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, exactamente ese era el problema!